# SQL Server + Select WHERE IN comma delimited string

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to select records where the Id exists in a comma delimited string but the query below doesn't return any results:

```
  SELECT * FROM [SellPost] WHERE CAST([AutoId] AS nchar(100)) 
   IN (SELECT [SellPostId] FROM [SellPostViewHistory]) -- SellPostId contains the delimited string
```

The statement 'SELECT [SellPostId] FROM [SellPostViewHistory]' will return 19,20,21 and if I replace the query with

```
   SELECT * FROM [SellPost] WHERE CAST([AutoId] AS nchar(100)) 
   IN (19,20,21)
```

it works. Can someone please kindly advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If your inner select returns an actual single string value, like '19, 20, 21', simple using IN won't work. You have to split it into table variable ([search SO there're many options on how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10914602/961695)).

Then you can either join your original query with this temp variable or run your IN statement against a SELECT from such table.

Answer (score 2):

Ok probably most people already know this but still this is one of the solution:

Create a split function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](
  @delimited NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @delimiter NVARCHAR(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @xml XML
  SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@delimited,@delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'

  INSERT INTO @t(val)
  SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as item
  FROM  @xml.nodes('/t') as records(r)
  RETURN
END
```

Usage:

```
 DECLARE @SellPostIds nvarchar(MAX)
   SET @SellPostIds = (SELECT [SellPostId] FROM [SellPostViewHistory])

   SELECT * FROM [SellPost] WHERE CAST([AutoId] AS nchar(100)) 
   IN (SELECT val FROM dbo.Split(@SellPostIds, ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a CSV to table split, you can have a UDF taking input as string and return a Table, make a join to these tables and work with your IN clause